# Get the position of a paragraphs entity in a nested template

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

I try to build an accordion or slider element with Paragraphs.

Therefore I create a Slider element which had slides. Unfortunately the first element should always looks different. I can do this with a CSS class, but how to figure out which is the first slide?

Slider:

```
<div class="feature-slider">
    <div class="feature-slider__slides">     
        <div class="feature-slider__slides-container">
            {{ content.field_feature_slider_slides }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Slide (which will loaded through Drupal Magic):

```
<div class="feature-slide {% if pos == 1 %}feature-slide--active{% endif %}">
  ...
</div>
```

**How can I get/set/access a variable (here pos) with the current position of the loop?**

The Slider uses Paragraphs to add several Slides. The is a template for the slider paragraph--slider.html.twig and paragraph--slide.html.twig for the slides. No For-Loops are involved here. Drupal/Paragraphs rendering the slides through the template with content.field_feature_slider_slides from the slider.

Answer (score 1):

For the Slide, are overriding the default field.html.twig template?
If yes, then you can use the Twig Loop variables:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html
e.g. loop.first

Comment: Thanks @Ismail but unfortunately it doesn't work. The slider is a file like

paragraph--slider.html.twig and the slide is
paragraph--slide.html.twig

There is no for loop involved. I am so sorry. It's really hard to explain for me.

Comment: @TobiasRedmann, this is the correct answer. Use the field template of the paragraph slide field. You can find it with Twig Debug. And for CSS it should be no problem, you often have to pick up classes on different levels of containers.